# Как определить top элемента в массиве с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. В моем коде есть массив $bricks, каждый элемент который попадает в этот массив имеет разный top и positon: absolute. Как можно определить top элемента в массиве. Я пробовал :

```
function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < $bricks.length; i++) {
                $bricks[i].offset().top) 
                }
}
```

Но это не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста выход. Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: К чему тут закрывающая скобка? К чему фигурные скобки? Простите, но что за наркомания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for( var i = 0; i < $bricks.length; i++ ){
    var offset = $bricks.eq(i).offset();
    if( offset != null ){
         console.log(offset.top);
    }
}

//  или
$bricks.each(function (){
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  if( offset != null ){
      console.log(offset.top);
  }
});
```

Comment: Супер, все работает отлично. Большое спасибо )))